# Ajax Form breaking PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making an upload website and I'm trying to add an upload progress bar.
For some reason, the Ajax form I am using in my scripts is breaking the PHP code, therefore, stopping it from uploading.

When I remove the Ajax form, the Javascript runs fine and the PHP manages to upload the file, but with it in, it breaks. Any ideas? Much appreciated.

```
<input type="submit" name="sub" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="upload_image();">



<div class='progress' id="progress_div">
    <div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
    <div class='percent' id='percent1'>0%</div>
</div>

<script>
function upload_image() 
{
    var bar = $('#bar');
    var percent = $('#percent');

    $('#myForm').ajaxForm({

        beforeSubmit: function() {
          document.getElementById("progress_div").style.display="block";
          var percentVal = '0%';
          bar.width(percentVal)
          percent.html(percentVal);
        },

        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
          var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
          bar.width(percentVal)
          percent.html(percentVal);
        },

         success: function() {
          var percentVal = '100%';
          bar.width(percentVal)
          percent.html(percentVal);
      },
  }); 
}
</script>
```

I'm using:

```
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
```

for the PHP

Comment: `$('#myForm').ajaxForm({...})` initialises your form with "ajaxForm" behaviour. It doesn't cause the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message from PHP?

If your willing to change your dependency from ajaxForm to jquery-ajax-progress (https://github.com/likerRr/jq-ajax-progress), you can do it with the following.

This assumes that the file you access can be found at /upload.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
        var_dump($_FILES['image']);
        $image = $_FILES['image'];
        move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['name']);                                
    }
?>

<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<div class='progress' style="display: none;">
    <div class='bar' ></div>
    <div class='percent' >0%</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
     .bar { 
        width: 0;
        background: #ccc;
        min-height: 1em;
     }
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jq-ajax-progress.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploadForm = $('form[enctype="multipart/form-data"]');
    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');

    $(uploadForm).submit(function (e) {        
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.progress').css('display','block');
        var formData = new FormData(uploadForm[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $(uploadForm).attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).uploadProgress(function (e) {
            // tracking uploading
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                var percentage = Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total);
                updateProgressBar(percentage);
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
            updateProgressBar(100);

            // TODO: Perform other complete action
            // console.log(result);
        });
    });

    function updateProgressBar(percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal);
        percent.html(percentVal);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I seem to be getting some errors:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (upload.php:72)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)`

with this change in script

Comment: Sorry, could you try removing that if statement, so the first line of the submit function is e.preventDefault().  I've used this script in a form that is validated elsewhere.

Comment: Ah that fixed that issue, next one though `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).uploadProgress is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (upload.php:82)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (jquery.js:3)`

Comment: I gave you a link to the wrong file! Can you copy the following file to your site, add in reference to it,  https://github.com/likerRr/jq-ajax-progress/blob/master/src/jq-ajax-progress.js
I've updated my answer above with this change

Comment: Seems to have fixed the above error, but no PHP is being ran again, same issue as original stated. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of your form action attribute, and can you share the contents of that file?  Have you tried running this through chrome, with the developer tools -> Network tab open.  What are the entries shown when you click the submit button?

Comment: OK Brad, I've create an upload.php file for you, which is now in my edited post above.  If you can copy the contents of my edited answer so that you can access it on http://localhost/upload.php, with a folder called /js in it, and the jq-ajax-progress.js in that.

You'll see this should work.  Previously I was testing this with a dot net project, but have just created a site with the upload in it.

Just as a check, your not uploading a file above your  upload_max_filesize size (8Mb)?

Comment: Hi again Oliver, thanks. I've tried it and the uploading bar now works, and the PHP is being triggered, but if I adjust the PHP code at such, such as adding a simple `echo "working!";` , it no longer works

Comment: You wont see anything like echo "working!"; after the submit on the page, as the response is returned to the javascript.  With chrome, open the developer tools, and look at the Network tab.  Alternatively, add document.write(result); to the function under the line // TODO: perform other complete action.  What I'd recomend though is that you redirect to another page.